# Expected value and variance of the sum $S_n^{(t)} = \sum_{i=1}^n1_{B_i^{(t)}}$ of indicator random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $A_1,A_2,\dots$ be independent and uniformly distributed random variables on $[0, 1]$. Define $B_n^{(t)} = \{A_n \leq t\}$ for $t \in [0, 1]$ as an event and $S_n^{(t)} = \sum_{i=1}^n1_{B_i^{(t)}}$ as a sum of indicator random variables. I'm trying to show that $\mathrm{Var}(S_n^{(t)}) \leq \frac{n}{4}$, but I'm not entirely sure on why my reasoning fails. So far I've done the following:

$E(S_n^{(t)}) = E\left(\sum_{i=1}^n1_{B_i^{(t)}}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^nE\left(1_{B_i^{(t)}}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^nP(B_i^{(t)}) = \sum_{i=1}^nP(B_i^{(t)}) = \sum_{i=1}^nP(\{A_i \leq t\}) = \sum_{i=1}^nF_{A_i}(t)$, where $F_{A_i}(t) = \int_0^t\frac{1}{1 - 0}dt = t$, so that $E(S_n^{(t)}) = \sum_{i=1}^n t = nt$. But then,
$\mathrm{Var}(S_n^{(t)}) = E\left(\left(S_n^{(t)} - nt\right)^2\right) = E\left(\left(S_n^{(t)}\right)^2\right) - nt = E\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(1_{B_i^{(t)}})^2 + 2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i + 1}^n(1_{B_i^{(t)}}*1_{B_j^{(t)}})\right)$, where $1_{B_i^{(t)}}*1_{B_j^{(t)}} = 1_{B_i^{(t)}\cap B_j^{(t)}}$, and the indicator r.v. is idempotent under the squaring, so that $\mathrm{Var}(S_n^{(t)}) = -nt + \sum_{i=1}^nE\left((1_{B_i^{(t)}})\right) + 2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i + 1}^nE\left(1_{B_i^{(t)}\cap B_j^{(t)}}\right) = -nt + nt + 2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i + 1}P(B_i^{(t)}\cap B_j^{(t)})$, where $P(B_i^{(t)}\cap B_j^{(t)}) = P(B_i^{(t)})P(B_j^{(t)}) = t^2$, so that $\mathrm{Var}(S_n^{(t)}) = 2t^2\cdot \frac{n(n + 1)}{2} = t^2n(n + 1)$, and I don't really see how this is at most $\frac{n}{4}$ due to the quadratic term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write the variance as $E[X^2]-E[X]^2$ I think you meant $-(pn)^2$ for the second term, which should cancel out the $n^2$ terms in the variance.

Comment: Thanks! I also had a typo of $p = t$. In any case, the $p^2n$ can be bounded by $\frac{n}{4}$, since the expected value of a uniform r.v. on the interval $[0, 1]$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.